# Failing cleanly if we match a type using SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'm toying with SFINAE and I try to generate a clean failure for three cases. The intend of `UseInput` is to switch an `Input` from `IsFree` to `IsUsed`. The `Input` types are packed inside an `Inputs` type (some kind of tuple). We access an `Input` by its index.

```
struct IsFree
{
};

struct IsUsed
{
};

template <typename Type, typename State>
struct Input
{
};

template <typename... DefaultInputs>
struct Inputs
{
};

template <typename Type, typename... DefaultInputs>
struct Inputs<Input<Type, IsFree>, DefaultInputs...>
    : public Inputs<DefaultInputs...>
{
};

template <typename Type, typename... DefaultInputs>
struct Inputs<Input<Type, IsUsed>, DefaultInputs...>
    : public Inputs<DefaultInputs...>
{
};

// UseInput creates a new Inputs type where an Input state is switched from IsFree to IsUsed
template <int index, typename LastInputs, typename NextInputs>
struct UseInput;

// We found the Input to switch
template <typename Type, typename... LastInputs, typename... NextInputs>
struct UseInput<0, Inputs<Input<Type, IsFree>, LastInputs...>, Inputs<NextInputs...>>
    : public UseInput<-1, Inputs<LastInputs...>, Inputs<NextInputs..., Input<Type, IsUsed>>>
{
};

// We try to switch an Input we shouldn't, this is an error
template <typename Type, typename... LastInputs, typename... NextInputs>
struct UseInput<0, Inputs<Input<Type, IsUsed>, LastInputs...>, Inputs<NextInputs...>>
{
};

// We processed the Inputs
template <int index, typename... NextInputs>
struct UseInput<index, Inputs<>, Inputs<NextInputs...>>
{
    typedef Inputs<NextInputs...> Result;
};

// Recursively process each Input
template <int index, typename Type, typename State, typename... LastInputs, typename... NextInputs>
struct UseInput<index, Inputs<Input<Type, State>, LastInputs...>, Inputs<NextInputs...>>
    : public UseInput<index - 1, Inputs<LastInputs...>, Inputs<NextInputs..., Input<Type, State>>>
{
};
```

These use cases work :

```
typedef Inputs<Input<float, IsFree>, Input<float, IsUsed>, Input<float, IsFree>> TestInputs;

typedef UseInput<0, TestInputs, Inputs<>>::Result Result0;
static_assert(std::is_same<Result0, Inputs<Input<float, IsUsed>, Input<float, IsUsed>, Input<float, IsFree>>>::value, "Unexpected type...");

typedef UseInput<2, TestInputs, Inputs<>>::Result Result2;
static_assert(std::is_same<Result2, Inputs<Input<float, IsFree>, Input<float, IsUsed>, Input<float, IsUsed>>>::value, "Unexpected type...");
```

These must fail :

```
typedef Inputs<Input<float, IsFree>, Input<float, IsUsed>, Input<float, IsFree>> TestInputs;

typedef UseInput<1, TestInputs, Inputs<>>::Result Result1;   // Already used Input

typedef UseInput<3, TestInputs, Inputs<>>::Result Result3;   // Bad index
typedef UseInput<-1, TestInputs, Inputs<>>::Result Result4;  //
```

The only solution I found is omit the `typedef Inputs<> Result;` but this seems bad way to report the errors and requires an additional index for testing the indices.

How can I fix my templates if I want a clean error reporting by the compiler ?

Comment: One day I will type these six letters in the right order, one day... ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd treat the list as a list, and iterate using the indices trick + parameter pack expansion.

Finally, a simple check that the resulting type isn't the same as the original will cover the case of "using" an input that was already used:

### The "API"

```
template <typename Type, typename State> struct Input {};

template <typename Type> using Used = Input<Type, struct IsUsed>;
template <typename Type> using Free = Input<Type, struct IsFree>;

template <typename... Input> struct InputList {};
```

### The Plumbing

Let's first make type functions to change state:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename Type, typename State> struct ChangeStateF;
    template <typename Type, typename State> struct ChangeStateF<Input<Type, IsFree>, State> { using type = Input<Type, State>; };
    template <typename Type, typename State> struct ChangeStateF<Input<Type, IsUsed>, State> { using type = Input<Type, State>; };
```

Which we can alias for convenience:

```
    template <typename Input> using UseInput  = ChangeStateF<Input, IsUsed>;
    template <typename Input> using FreeInput = ChangeStateF<Input, IsFree>;
```

Now all we need is to conditionally apply such a change

```
    template <bool C, template <typename...> class F, typename T>
    using apply_if = std::conditional<C, typename F<T>::type, T>;
```

to all the elements in an `InputList` by index:

```
    template<size_t N, template <typename...> class F, typename... I, size_t... Idx>
    constexpr auto apply_at(InputList<I...>, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
        return InputList<typename apply_if<Idx == N, F, I>::type...>{};
    }
```

The `index_sequence` is a trivial type included (with C++14) and we can forward from an overload without it:

```
    template<size_t N, template <typename...> class F, typename... I>
    constexpr auto apply_at(InputList<I...> l) {
        return apply_at<N, F>(l, std::index_sequence_for<I...>{});
    }
```

Now to detect indices out of bounds or changes that didn't have any effect (e.g. the input was already in the required state):

```
    template<size_t N, template <typename...> class F, typename... I>
    constexpr auto mutate_at(InputList<I...> l) {
        auto r = apply_at<N, F>(l);
        static_assert(not std::is_same<decltype(r), decltype(l)>{}, "Invalid Mutation");
        return r;
    }
```

### Wait, We Don't Want Functions, We Want Types!

This is 'modern style' meta programming, let's leave the detail namespace:

```
    template<size_t N, typename L>
    constexpr auto use_at(L x) { return mutate_at<N, UseInput>(x); }

    template<size_t N, typename L>
    constexpr auto free_at(L x) { return mutate_at<N, FreeInput>(x); }
}
```

Now, we're back in "type land":

```
template <std::size_t N, typename List> using Use   = decltype(detail::use_at<N>(List{}));
template <std::size_t N, typename List> using Clear = decltype(detail::free_at<N>(List{}));
```

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8194d3bfa86b2de7)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() { 
    using Inputs = InputList<Free<float>, Used<float>, Used<float> >;
    using New = Use<0, Inputs>;
    //using Oops = Use<0, New>; doesn't compile

    std::cout << typeid(Inputs).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(New).name() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
InputList<Input<float, IsFree>, Input<float, IsUsed>, Input<float, IsUsed> >
InputList<Input<float, IsUsed>, Input<float, IsUsed>, Input<float, IsUsed> >
```

Uncommenting the line with `Oops` would lead to

```
main.cpp:36:9: error: static_assert failed "Invalid Mutation"
        static_assert(not std::is_same<decltype(r), decltype(l)>{}, "Invalid Mutation");
```

Comment: A lots of good ideas but all the errors (IsUsed and bad indices) are checked by a unique static_assert and you don't understand much about the error without looking at the whole pile of the instantiation. I hope SFINAE can do better.

Comment: SFINAE cannot do better. The programmer might do better. Honestly, I would not fret it, unless this is a highly specific application domain (standalone embedded utility library?). For the precise reason that anything else would simply be better served by non-static interface.

Comment: So, I was just being the opinionated bastard refusing to complicate code for no reason. If you are sure your concerns are valid, just code it up! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de2f41f5c3c521c4

Comment: This is just an attempt at testing the limits of SFINAE and learning C++11 and newer features. Having an opinion is never bad... ^^

Comment: The problem with sfinae is that it's "dynamite": it explodes unless it's in deduced context. And it's tedious to get it into that context. (I remember finding a case where I couldn't force it recently but I don't recall the specifics anymore. I should learn to ask these things on SO :))